# Calling method from different class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I've got an ArrayList of objects that need to be printed out on the screen. I have got a button and a listener that should call a method in a class that extends JPanel which is added in a MainFrame class.

This is the method I want to call in a class called AddOrderPanel.

```
    public void addLCheese(){ 
         BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal("8.99");
         CheesePizza largeCheese = new CheesePizza("Large Cheese/Tomato",price);
         OrderItem laCheese = new OrderItem(largeCheese,1);
         System.out.println(largeCheese.getDescription()+" "+largeCheese.getPrice()+" " +laCheese.testArray());
          JPanel order = new JPanel();
         order.setBackground(Color.blue);
      order.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,50));
        add(order,BorderLayout.CENTER);
     revalidate();

}
```

And this is my listener code :

```
        lCheese.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 AddOrderPanel orderPanel;
              orderPanel.addLCheese();

            }
      });
```

When I try it it returns NullPointerException, ideas?

My Panel Object.

```
 private JFrame myMainFrameObject;
    AddOrderPanel(JFrame theMainFr){  
    myMainFrameObject = theMainFr;
          this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
         setBackground(Color.red);
         setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,0));     
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning `orderPanel` to anything before calling `orderPanel.addLCheese()`.

Answer (score 1):

In your listener make this change to get the JFrame and then create a new instance of AddOrderPanel

```
  lCheese.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           Component component = (Component) e.getSource();
           JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getRoot(component);
           AddOrderPanel orderPanel = new AddOrderPanel(frame);
           orderPanel.addLCheese();

        }
  });
```

Comment: I cannot do that since the code for my AddOrderPanel requires a frame.        @Edited Question

Comment: @ChrisA : Edited my answer to reflect your constraint.